# Layer backed NSView, disable addSubview animation

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I have a layer backed NSView that seems to implicitly animate the adding of a subview without calling the animator method.  For example:

[self addSubview:(NSView*)aView];

or calling

[[self animator] addSubview:(NSView*)aView];

results in the same fade in animation for adding a subview. Is there anyway to disable this or is this not supposed to happen?  I'm running Lion 10.7.2

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
[CATransaction begin];
[CATransaction setDisableActions:YES];
[self addSubview:(NSView *)aView];
[CATransaction commit];
```

Comment: Thanks, but it seems like the slow drawing I'm seeing is not actually an animation but a lag that is caused by me having to reorder the subviews, apparently layer-back views do not like reorder the subviews and introduces a lag in the drawing the could be perceived as an animation. I think I am just going to have to impliment a custom layer view to get the functionality that I need.